# Sum of $k^\text{th}$ Powers of the First $n$ Natural Numbers is a Perfect Square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Question:**
>
> If for some $k$ and $\forall$ $n>2017, n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exist an $x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $$1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k=x^2$$
> then $k=3$.

---

**Minor clarification:**

The question says : $\forall n$. Now, we know that $1^3+2^3+..+n^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$.

But, **for all** $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>2017$, you won't get some positive integer $x$ such that $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k=x^2$. You will get such $x$ only when $k=3$. I don't think there's any particular significance of $2017$ here.

---

How do we even start this? It looks so weird.

How to proceed after that?

My idea is to use:

$$\sum_{x=0}^n (x+1)^{k+1}-x^{k+1}=n^k \left({k \choose 0} + {k-1 \choose 0} + \cdots + {0 \choose 0}\right) + n^{k-1} \left({k \choose 1} + {k-1 \choose 1} + \cdots + {1 \choose 1}\right) + \cdots + n^{k-k}\left(k\choose k \right)$$.

The $\text {LHS}$ equals $\left(n+1\right)^{k+1}-1$. And we have the $1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$ term in the $\text {RHS}$

But I don't know if  his helps to show that the sum of the $k^\text {th}$ powers will be a non perfect sqaure $\forall n>2017$

We can also do something like this-
If $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k=x^2$, then $x^2+(n+1)^k=y^2$. And then, $y^2+(n+2)^k=z^2$ and so on.
First of all, is $a^2+n^k=b^2$ possible for all $n>2017$ (though $2017$ hasn't got any special significance) and for a particular $k$ (and needless to mention,  $a,b$ are not constants since $n$ is variable)?

But, how do we show that it won't hold unless $k=3$?

Comment: Take a look at [this link of wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). I think it will be useful. My idea is to find a closed form for the LHS and then proceed.

Comment: @H.R. I know about Faulhauber formula. But it will be hard for me to consider Bernaulli numbers and show. I don't have much idea about Bernaulli numbers.

Comment: Is the theorem stating that it just hold for $k=3$? You said that you can prove $k=3$!

Comment: @H.R. The question has been edited and everything has been fixed. Please check

Comment: I am still confused! If you can prove that $k=3$ then the theorem is proved! Is $k=3$ the hypothesis or the thing to be proved!?

Comment: @H.R. Oh.. It has to be proved that $k$ can be nothing but $3$

Comment: So why you are expressing that "Proving $k=3$ isn't​ hard for me"?

Comment: @H.R. Okay, I meant something different. Anyway, removed. I meant that I can show that $1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$ can be expressed as a sqaure can be shown by me. But I can't show that for $k>3$, then LHS won't be a perfect square

Comment: Is my edition of the question OK?

Comment: @H.R. Yes it's quite okay. But​ I don't think that it's a theorem.

Comment: It is a theorem you want to prove!? Isn't it? Or it is a conjecture?

Comment: @H.R. Not a theorem. Let's change it to **question**

Comment: It seems to be a tough question! I don't have any idea right now but will think on it. :) Is it some question on Olympiads or something? :D

Comment: @H.R. Yes, Olympiads

Comment: mmmm, Here is a raw idea. According to your last statements maybe a proof by induction is possible. First show that it cannot happen for $k=4$ and then use induction to prove it cannot happen for any $k>4$.

Comment: @H.R. Is it possible that way? To show "cannot happen" using induction in this case is quite hard.

Comment: Using the direct approach seems to be much harder! :) I think using **similar** proofs for [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) and type of arguments at the end of question can help to show it cannot happen for $k\ge4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer posted by OP (solved by some AoPSer)**

$f(n)=1^m+...n^m$, obvious, that $m$ is odd.
$f(n)<n^{m+1}$
Let $p$ -big prime.
$f(p-1)=x^2,f(p)=y^2 \to p^m=y^2-x^2 \to m=a+b;b>a,x=\frac{p^b-p^a}{2}$
$4x^2=(p^b-p^a)^2=4f(p-1)<4(p-1)^{m+1}$
$p^{2b}+p^{2a}-2p^{a+b}<4p^{a+b}(p-1)$
$p^{2b-2a}+1-2p^{b-a}<4p^{b-a}(p-1)$
Let $p^{b-a}=q$
$q^2-q(4p-2)+1<0 \to q<4p-2<p^2 \to b-a=1$

So if $m=2k+1$ then $x=\frac{p^k(p-1)}{2}$ and so $f(p-1)=(\frac{p^k(p-1)}{2})^2$
We can prove, that for $k\geq 2$ is true, that $f(n)<\frac{(n+1)^{2k+2}}{6}$
$(\frac{p^k(p-1)}{2})^2<\frac{p^{2k+2}}{6}$
$3p^{2k}(p-1)^2<2p^{2k+2}$
$p^2-6p+3<0$ -wrong for big $p$
So $k=0,1 \to m=1,3$ and easy to check, that $m=3$ is answer

Comment: (+1) nice job. :) Solved by what? That would be nice if you add some more details on each step. :)

Comment: Could you please tell me what is AoPSer?